# How to find the biggest triangle drawable between pre-existent lines

Tags: algorithm, lines, intersect

I have a rectangular plane filled with randomly drawn straight lines (of which i know the vertices coordinates), with different lenghts, and i need to find which triangles can i draw (possibly the biggest ones) inside it that intersecates with the least lines possible, is there an existing algorithm that could work here, or some way that you think i can relate this problem to a more common one? thanks in advice

Comment: This is a rather ill-defined problem statement. How do you decide that one triangle or a set of triangles is better than another?

Comment: You're right, my English isn't the best, what I meant is that I need to find the triangles I can draw that intersect the lower number of lines possible, that would result in a single triangle, which would be my final result,  or in a collection of different triangles, from which I would choose the one with the biggest surface

Comment: So the answer is one triangle, not a set. It is still not clear how you decide between a bigger triangle that intersects more lines, and a smaller triangle that intersects fewer lines.

Comment: Yes, in the end I need a single triangle, and between the two I would need the smaller one that has less intersections, as the main priority is to have less intersections as possible

Comment: So in fact you need zero intersections, as it is better than anything with non-zero intersections.

Comment: You can always draw a triangle far away from all lines. It will have zero intersections and as big area as you want...

Comment: Yes, but in the case there isn't  any possible triangle with zero intersections, I would still want I get the triangle with the less intersections possible

Comment: @xKylesx, you can _always_ have a triangle with zero intersections, just take three points as close to each other as possible.

Comment: It seems that you do limit the set of triangles under consideration somehow. Can you post some picture and show which triangles are allowed and which not?